# creating jenkins jobs with ansible

Tags: git, jenkins, vagrant, ansible, jenkins-cli

I'm working on a project to deploy a jenkins CI server on centos7 using ansible
And I'm having problems creating jenkins jobs from an xml template using ansible.

Everything works fine so far, but now i want to be able to create jobs, and give them some basic configuration from an xml file using ansible. My solution was the following command from jenkins-cli:

```
sudo java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 create-job Job_test1 < Job_test1.xml
```

this works perfectly when entered manually in the centos7 box, but when i put it into ansible and run it:

```
- name: create jenkins jobs with xml files
  sudo: yes
  command: "java -jar {{ jenkins.cli_dest }} -s http://localhost:8080 create-job {{ item.name }} < {{ jenkins_dest }}/{{ item.xml_name }}"
  with_items: jenkins_jobs
```

it gives the following error message:

```
stderr: Too many arguments: <
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar create-job NAME
Creates a new job by reading stdin as a configuration XML file.
```

Does anyone know a solution to this? 
As far as I can see I'm doing it properly(since the command works when not entered by ansible)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [command module](http://docs.ansible.com/command_module.html) doesn't support input and output redirection since it doesn't pass the command string to a shell. This is what its documentation says:

> It will not be processed through the shell, so variables like $HOME and operations like "<", ">", "|", and "&" will not work (use the [shell module](http://docs.ansible.com/shell_module.html) if you need these features).

So:

```
- name: create jenkins jobs with xml files
  sudo: yes
  shell: "java -jar {{ jenkins.cli_dest }} -s http://localhost:8080 create-job {{ item.name }} < {{ jenkins_dest }}/{{ item.xml_name }}"
  with_items: jenkins_jobs
```

Answer (score 9):

I manage my jenkins CI/CD pipelines and setup with ansible, and I rely heavily on available libraries (groovy DSL, python jenkins-job-builder) and template the guts of the the jenkins XML config using jinja2.
I got asked to showcase what can be done with ansible at a local meetup, and have been working some code that I will be delivering and sharing at that meetup in the new year.
I seriously think this stuff could help you a lot,  I currently use this setup in my current project and can't imagine managing jenkins any other way.

https://github.com/Azulinho/ansible-jenkins-showcase

Comment: although my question was already answered, I greatly appreciate your reply, and I'm sure this will indeed be very helpful to me.

Comment: @azul Do you have any more examples on how to convert JJB yaml code to ansible? Does this require configuring the ansible plugin on Jenkins side?

Answer (score 0):

You can use shell redirection by executing the shell. For example, the command 'sh "echo test > hello.txt"' will work as intended. Just wrap the whole command with something like '/bin/sh "java ...>..."'.